# toggleClass in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

jQuery:

```
var obj = this;

obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

angularjs:

```
var delement = "";
$scope.dd = function($event) {
    delement = $($event.target);
    delement.toggleClass('active');
};
```

It works fine in system browser, not doesn't work in a mobile application (with ionic angular).

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you using both jQuery and angular to perform the same task?  There's not enough context to be sure but I suspect the reason it's not working is because one's toggling the class on and the other immediately toggles it back off again.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should not try to use jQuery inside angular, but do it the angular way :

inside your view

```
      <div ng-class="{active : isMyDivActive}" ></div>
```

and inside your controller :

```
      $scope.dd = function(){
          $scope.isMyDivActive = !$scope.isMyDivActive;
      };
```

Comment: above code ...first time its apply active class next click not removed that active class.. not working like toggle apply active  next click remove active

Comment: if($scope.isMyDivActive){
      $scope.isMyDivActive = false;
    }else{
      $scope.isMyDivActive = true;
    }

Comment: @Subha I corrected the stupid mistake I made in my code